# get latest of each out of one rails model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have one model, which I save changes witch happens to certain person. I want to get now the latest state of all person.

so I need to:
- order: created_at asc.
- find_all: limit: one change each person

how can I accomplish that?

Thanks,
Markus

Comment: If you want the latest (newest) records, then you want created_at DESC, not ASC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `:group`, which translates to a `GROUP BY` statement in SQL.

```
YourModel.all(:order => 'created_at DESC', :group => :person_id)
```

Comment: ORDER  is applied after GROUP. So the results returned will not contain the last state.

Comment: You are correct, KandadaBoggu. I'm pretty sure, however, that there's a solution using GROUP BY and MAX that would not require a subquery.

Comment: To get all the fields of a matching row in the OrderState table you have to use a query. This is a classic problem. E.g: List the employee details with highest salary in each department etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
person_hash = OrderState.maximum(:created_at, :group => :person_id)
person_hash.each |person_id, created_at|
  state = OrderState.find_by_person_id_and_created_at(person_id, created_at)
end
```

Refer to the ActiveRecord [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html#M002192) for more details.

If you want to do most of the calculations in the DB, try this:

```
OrderState.find_by_sql("SELECT A.* FROM order_states A,
                (SELECT person_id, MAX(BA.created_at) AS created_at 
                 FROM order_states BA 
                 GROUP BY BA.person_id
                 ) AS B
WHERE  A.person_id = B.person_id AND 
       A.created_at = B.created_at")
```

In both approaches you should index `created_at` column. If you have millions of users this is not a good strategy. You should store the last state in the Person table.